# .NET Core Pomelo EF for MySQL - unpredictable times for simple INSERT

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have been using Pomelo EF since the 4.x days of .NET Core and all is working well, but I have one API endpoint where its job is to INSERT a row into a fairly simple table.  Most of the time this command is executed and takes less than 200ms in the db to complete.

On other occasions this dbCommand, this simple INSERT statement, can take upwards of 20 seconds to complete.  I can't seem to find out what is going on, the last call I see is a ManualResetEventSlim.Wait() from the DataDog trace.

Any idea what could be happening here?  Anything else I should be using to investigate?

[image: DataDog Trace]

Answer (score 0):

Start by isolating the issue.

Enable the MySQL [Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html) and then check, whether your query makes it into the log or not.

*(Update your Question with the results, I then update my answer.)*